# Ryzen (Zen2) super slow VMWare Workstation emulation on Windows 10. But why?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, performance, vmware-workstation

I know, kind of a vague question but I have nowhere else to turn to.
We wish to run virtual machines on one of our work machines and we can't figure out why it is so slow.

No matter what guest OS we try, like Windows 10, Server 2022, or various Linux distributions - everything feels slow. It feels slower than a 5-year-old laptop running said OS. It feels slower than the other workstation with its old 4790K hosting a VM. We've tried to disable/enable 3D acceleration, and change various settings we could find in the Settings, but nothing.

How would I describe slow? Like running Windows 10 on an SSD, with a Core2Quad CPU in 2022. The windows open sluggishly, the interface feels just kinda slow everywhere. If I do any kind of task, like open a Chrome and open a page, the whole host slows to a crawl.

The CPU performs adequately on the host OS and is achieving similar scores to other, similar builds.
And on top of that? Virtualbox is incredibly snappy. It is so much faster compared to VMWare Workstation. Virtualbox feels like using the native system, it is that fast.

Why not just use Virtualbox?
Because it has no OpenGL support, it only has a super basic 3D capability.
Our test cases would require somewhat both of them. VMWare just has what we need.
Why not use Hyper-V?
Same thing as Virtualbox. Lack of 2D/3D capability, and if you enable Hyper-V on Windows, it "cripples" the Host by effectively turning it into a VM as well.
Why not use Linux as host-OS?
No 3D acceleration under guests for Linux as far as I am aware. We also rely on Windows software on the host during daily work/tasks, so it would just mean more work/workarounds. So even if we added a second GPU, it would not solve much.

The host hardware in question:

- X570 ASUS motherboard
- Ryzen 5900X
- 64GB DDR4 3200MTz
- GTX 1060 GPU
- OS is Windows 10 Pro, build 21H2
- VMWare Workstation 16.2.3
- Host and Guest Storage is the same NVMe SSD drive

What we have tried:

- AMD-V is enabled. Virtualbox works great.
- Updating BIOS: no change
- Used Curve Optimizer to enable higher-boost: no change
- Make sure the VM is loaded into reserved RAM (vmware setting)
- Disabling/Enabling 3D acceleration of guest
- Disabling Windows Defender security mitigations on Host

Any ideas or tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: Very general question.   I have a Windows 11 Pro machine with VMware Workstation V16 newest on a fast SDD.  Guests have 3D acceleration enabled.  CPUs  1 with 2 cores.  Do NOT assign too many CPUs - will slow down.  Memory 3 or 4 GB for a machine. My Guest machines - fast like normal. Windows Defender running on Host machine no issue.

Comment: OpenGL2 is definitely possible in VirtualBox 6 and OpenGL3 can be made possible with some tweaks until the devs officially support it: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=101304